# Creating single activity to rate products based on three different standards

Tags: android, android-listview, android-xml, android-gridview

I want to create an activity with four columns. The first column would be automatically filled with the names of the products (from database) and the other three with rating bars.

Example:

NAME     | PRICE|DESIGN| COMPANY

product1 | rtb1 | rtb2 | rtb3

product2 | rtb1 | rtb2 | rtb3

product3 | rtb1 | rtb2 | rtb3

product4 | rtb1 | rtb2 | rtb3

product5 | rtb1 | rtb2 | rtb3

When I click on a rating bar a new activity will begin contaning 5 rating bars (subcategories) the sum of which will be shown at the "mother" ratingbar of my primary acrivity.

I just want to know which is the best posible way to develop this. Thanks...

Comment: Are you wanting the parent rating bar to be based on ratings from all the users of the app, or just the single user?

Comment: I'm assuming it is for all users. rating bars for a single user is pretty useless

Comment: The rating categories are not definite yet. In ortder to take the final rating the user has to rate 5 different categories. The parent rating bar is usefull only to display the final result. In total we have 15 different categories devided in three more general. Thats why i use 3 rating bars in my main activity.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a ListView with a CursorAdapter if there are more products than can fit on one screen.
There are a few nuances with working with selectable parts of a ListView item but all of the entries will be of the same form you only have to solve this once.
It will be much more performant to use a ListView with a CursorAdapter than a GridView.

This is especially nice if you use a dual fragment list detail tablet view since it will use the devices real estate nicely like this:

[image: Multi-pane layout]